# AJAX recebe JSONP como "undefined"

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, jsonp

primeiramente queria dizer que andei pesquisando por isso aqui no fórum e achei algumas perguntas semelhantes, porém nenhuma resposta funcionou aqui.

Seguinte, tenho um arquivo php no servidor que se conecta ao banco, faz uma consulta e retorna em formato json os dados que preciso:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:','*');
header('Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8');

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~ E_NOTICE);// para nao mostrar undefined variable
require("config.php");

$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];

$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM login WHERE usuario = :usuario AND senha = :senha");

$sql->bindValue(":usuario",$usuario,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindValue(":senha",$senha,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->execute();


$ln = $sql->fetchAll();
$n = $sql->rowCount();

if ($sql) {
    if ($n>0){
       //$retorno['status'] = "s"; 
       $retorno['dados'] = $ln;
   echo $_GET['callback'] . '('.json_encode($retorno).')';
       //echo json_encode($retorno);
    }else{
        //$retorno['status'] = "n";
        echo $_GET['callback'] . '('.json_encode($retorno).')';
        //echo (json_encode($retorno));
    }

}
```

Porém, na hora de eu receber ele usando ajax(por uma fonte externa), só vem o 'status', e o 'retorno' vem como 'undefined', e assim não consigo obter o resultado correto para fazer a operação.

Segue o javascript:

```
$(function () {

function onAppReady() {
    if (navigator.splashscreen &&     navigator.splashscreen.hide) { // Cordova API detected
        navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    }
}
$('form[name=form-login]').submit( function(){  
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        crossDomain:true,
        url: 'http://www.minhaurl.com.br/api/meuphp.php?callback=?',
        dataType:'jsonp',
        contentType  : "application/json",
        data: $(this).serialize() // pega os dados do form

    }).done(function(data){

            console.log(data);


            if (data.status == "s"){
               //faz a ação desejada

            }
            else if (data.status == "n"){
                // sempre vem status:n, pois não vem dados para fazer a operação
                alert('Credenciais Inválidas');
            }
            else {
                alert('...');
            }
        })
    .fail(function(data, textStatus, errorThrown){
         alert('falhou');  
         console.log(data);    
        });
   return false; 
});
```

Ou seja, não consigo me comunicar com o servidor através de uma fonte externa. Alguma ajuda? Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ATUALIZAÇÃO 23/05/2016**

Bom dia o seu retorno informado é um application/json porém o seu retorno é um script remova o header `header('Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8');` no seu PHP e no seu ajax onde tá `dataType:'jsonp'`coloque `dataType:'script'` assim vai funcionar

**FIM**

se ele está retornando isso provavelmente é problema de encoding.
Tente dar um `utf8_encode()` ou `utf8_decode` antes do `json_encode()`

> Mas como é array tente ver no PDO de startar a conexão com o SET_NAMES como abaixo.

***Obs:** Caso não funcione verifique no notepad++ se o seu arquivo está com o encoding em utf-8

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
//header('Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8');

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~ E_NOTICE);// para nao mostrar undefined variable
require("config.php");

$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];
$pdo->exec("SET NAMES utf8"); //aqui eu mudo para UTF-8
$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM login WHERE usuario = :usuario AND senha = :senha");

$sql->bindValue(":usuario",$usuario,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindValue(":senha",$senha,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->execute();


$ln = $sql->fetchAll();
$n = $sql->rowCount();

if ($sql) {
    if ($n>0){
       //$retorno['status'] = "s"; 
       $retorno['dados'] = $ln;
   echo $_GET['callback'] . '('.json_encode($retorno).')';
       //echo json_encode($retorno);
    }else{
        //$retorno['status'] = "n";
        echo $_GET['callback'] . '('.json_encode($retorno).')';
        //echo (json_encode($retorno));
    }

}
```

Comment: Oi, fiz isso o que você falou, porém continua com o erro.

Comment: Já sei, estou corrigindo a resposta...

Comment: Hiago só tem um erro que não notou `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:','*');`, o correto é `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` atualiza ae :)

Comment: opa, verdade... mas o problema não é de CORS é sobre um resultado esperado de maneira incorreta. Ele espera um JSON e devolve um script

Comment: Mas mesmo assim atualizei obrigado.